# Definition of charge with Hodge star

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

I understand the definition of charge given by

$$ Q = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{D-1}} \text{d}^{D-1}x J^0. \tag{1}$$

In Carroll’s *Spacetime and Geometry* book (pg. 455) he writes

> Start by imagining that we have a conserved current $J^\mu$, by which we mean
> $$\nabla_\mu J^\mu = 0. \tag{2}$$
> [...] we can translate the conservation condition into
> $$\text{d} (\star J) = 0. \tag{3}$$
> Then we define the charge passing through a hypersurface $\Sigma$ via
> $$ Q = - \int_\Sigma \star J. \tag{4}$$

I am not sure how (4) relates to (1). Aren’t we now integrating over all components of $J$ and not just $J^0$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $J$ is a 1-form

$$J= J_0 dx^0 + \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} J_i dx^i,$$
where I have separated the time component visually from the spatial components. Now suppose that the hypersurface $\Sigma$ is a volume in the spatial only directions. By the definition of the [Hodge star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator), we see that the volume form of the hypersurface $\Sigma$ can be expressed as $\star dx^0\sim dx^1 \wedge ...\wedge dx^{D-1}$. There will be other terms in the integration that contain $dx^0$, but since the time component is constant (the interval of integration has measure 0), those integrals will vanish.